# Question regarding elementary symmetric functions

Tags: symmetric-functions

How to prove the following equalities?

$$\sum_{k\ge1}\sum_{\substack{J \subseteq \mathbb N \\ J = \{i_1,\dots,i_k\}}}\big((-1)^{k-1}\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_{i_j}\big) = x_1 + x_2 + \cdots = e_1.$$

More generally, for a fixed $k$,

$$\sum_{m\ge1}\sum_{\substack{J \subseteq \mathbb N \\ J = \{i_1,\dots,i_m\}}}\sum_{\substack{J^{'} \subseteq J \\ J^{'} = \{i_{a_1},\dots,i_{a_k}\} \\ 1 \le a_i \le m}}\big((-1)^{k-1}\prod_{j=1}^{k}x_{i_j}\big) = (-1)^k e_k.$$
where $e_k$ is the kth elementary symmetric function.

It looks like a telescopic sum where only the $k=1$ case survives in the LHS of the first equation. But I am unable to come up with a concrete crisp argument.

Kindly share your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: The first sum can perhaps be expressed as some type of plethysm.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Can you please explain the composition? Thank you.

Comment: The sexond equality can't hold -- it is not homogeneous. Sure one  of the sum signs shouldn't be a product sign?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Sorry. There was a typo. I have changed the innermost sum into the product. Now, each monomial appearing in the LHS of the second equation has total degree k. Therefore homogeneous.

Comment: There are still some bugs in the second formula. The $\left(-1\right)^{k-1}$ should be a $\left(-1\right)^{m-1}$ sign perhaps? And I assume $k$ is fixed but $m$ is not? Are you really asking for a proof of $\sum\limits_{J \subseteq \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}} \left(-1\right)^{\left|J\right|-1} \sum\limits_{K \subseteq J;\  \left|K\right| = k} \prod\limits_{i \in K} x_i = 0$ for given $n$ and $k <n$ ? If so, it's an easy matter of interchanging the two summation signs.

Comment: Also, the sums aren't well-defined for an infinite set of variables. Each $x_i$ will appear infinitely often.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I have edited the question. Also, I want $(-1)^{k-1}$ only in the second expression. Everything we want in the level of formal series, so we don't need to worry about the convergence. Thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example, say, writing out the first few terms in lexicographic order? I am talking about convergence in the formal sense: for example, $x_1 - \left(x_1 + x_2\right) + \left(x_1 + x_2 + x_3\right) - \left(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4\right) \pm \cdots$ is not well-defined. Or do you have a way to make this well-defined?